# Bugzilla - Restrict changing bug status based on roles

Tags: workflow, roles, bugzilla

We want to define roles for the bug status workflow in this way:

- Person who files a bug
- Person who confirms the bug
- Person who resolves the bug
- Person who verifies the bug

We want to force that each person is a different person.

Answer (score 0):

We can give permissions(who can file a bug, who can confirm a bug) to a group of persons in product permissions.

Administration->products->Edit Group access controls

Read the instructions from that page and give the appropriate permissions to each group.

Sorry, I don't know about the remaining two permissions.
Person who resolves the bug
Person who verifies the bug